# How can I find the events that can be triggered from tvml DOM?

Tags: tvos, tvml, tvjs

From [Beginning tvOS Development with TVML Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114886/beginning-tvos-development-with-tvml-tutorial).

I am confused when adding an event to DOM. In this code

```
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
  //...
  //inside resourceLoader.loadResource...
  var doc = Presenter.makeDocument(resource);
  doc.addEventListener("select", Presenter.load.bind(Presenter)); //add this line
  Presenter.pushDocument(doc);
  //...
}
```

Where does `"select"` come from?

How can I know that `"select"` event can be fired from some elements, for example, a button ?

Is there any document on this ?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer. According to [TVML Catalog: Using TVML Templates](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Listings/client_js_Presenter_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016505-client_js_Presenter_js-DontLinkElementID_6) sample code:

> For a complete list of available events, see the TVMLKit DOM
>   Documentation.

---

After searching for a while, I found `TVElementEventType` in [TVViewElement Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLKit/Reference/TVViewElement_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/TVElementEventType)

```
enum TVElementEventType : Int {
    case Play
    case Select
    case HoldSelect
    case Highlight
    case Change
}
```

These are events that can be triggered from tvml elements.